# Flex 4: Skins ArrayCollection as dataprovider to an ItemRenderer of a List

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer, skin, arraycollection

**Objective:** I would like to pass Skins to an itemRenderer (which is a Button) of a List, and be able to skin every button in that List.

This is what I have:

**List:**

```
<s:List itemRenderer="renderers.ItemRenderer" dataProvider="{collectionWorkspace}" />
```

**ArrayCollection:**

```
<s:ArrayCollection id="collectionWorkspace">
    <comp:Layout1 />
    <comp:Layout2 />
    <comp:Layout3 />
    <comp:Layout4 />
    <comp:Layout5 />
</s:ArrayCollection>
```

The Layouts are Skin classes with HostComponent Button.

**ItemRenderer:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
    </s:states>

    <s:Button skinClass="{data}"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

**I get an error** (fixed for clarification):
Error: Skin for Application....Button1 cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are handing the `skinClass` property an instance of the skin class, not the actual class (which the button needs to create its own instance of the skin class).

If you can, the best thing to do would be to make `collectionWorkspace` be an array of Class objects, not of instances.

```
<s:ArrayCollection id="collectionWorkspace">
    <fx:Class>yourPkg.Layout1</fx:Class>
    <fx:Class>yourPkg.Layout2</fx:Class>
    <fx:Class>yourPkg.Layout3</fx:Class>
    <fx:Class>yourPkg.Layout4</fx:Class>
    <fx:Class>yourPkg.Layout5</fx:Class>
</s:ArrayCollection>
```

If you can't do that, you should be able to pull out the class of the instance and pass it to the `skinClass`.

```
<s:Button skinClass="{Object(data).constructor}"/>
```

**EDIT:**

The binding by default won't work because `data` starts off as `null` before it gets initialized with the class.  If you give it `null`, you will get the exception.  To fix it, you will need to return the default for the time between `null` and value:

```
<s:Button skinClass="{data != null ? data as Class : spark.skins.spark.ButtonSkin}"/>
```

I tried doing this with an `ArrayCollection` using some button skins.  It worked.

Comment: The Edited Button SkinClass value worked for me well! Thanks Brian. I hope others would find value in this as well.